# mapping from rest response

Tags: arrays, rxjs, angular8

I am working in an example with the Dog Api (https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all), the response for the breeds endpoint is something like that:

```
{
    "message": {
           "affenpinscher": [],
           "african": [],
           "airedale": [],
           "akita": [],
           "appenzeller": [],
           "australian": ["shepherd"]
}
```

I need that my breed service, returns an observable of Breed

```
export class Breed {
    name : String;  
    subbreeds : String[]
}
```

This call is returning an object with the property `message`. How I can map in my service for return an `Observable<Breed[]>` from that API Rest response.

```
getAll() : Observable<Breed[]> {  
    return this.http.get<Breed[]>("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all");   
}
```

Comment: share the code you are using to make the call. And should it return a `Breed` or `Breed[]`

Answer (score 0):

Actually this question is nothing about rxjs and angular 8, it about JavaScript.

```
export class Breed {
  // public modifier is a short hand for this.name = name
  constructor(public name: string, public subbreeds: string[]) {}
}

class Service {
  getAll() {
    return this.http
      .get<Breed[]>('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all')
      .pipe(
        map(data => // map here is a rxjs operator, do not confuse with JS array's map
          // Object.entries is convert Object's key value to entries [key, value] array
          Object.entries(data.message).map( // JS array map method mapping each entry to Breed instance
            // destructing from entry and return a Breed instance
            ([breed, subbreed]) => new Breed(breed, subbreed)
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

If you not sure about any term or method, please check MDN and RxJS official document